# java:29: error: cost has private access in RetailItem

Tags: java

Alright so I need help here I created a cash register java file and a retailItem file in my cash register file it cant read a section i put in retailItem because its private. So my question is how do i access that private variable that i wrote in my retailItem class into the cash register file

So here's my code for retailItem

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
public class RetailItem
{
 private String description;
 private double price;
 private double unitsOnHand;
 private CostData cost;


public void setDescription(String userDescription)
{ 
  description = userDescription;

}

public void setPrice(double p)
{
  price = p;
}


public void setUnitsOnHand(double userUnitsOnHand)
{ 
  unitsOnHand = userUnitsOnHand;

}

public String getDescription()
{
  return description;
}
public double getPrice()
{
  return price;
}

public double getUnitsOnHand()
{
  return unitsOnHand;
}



 public RetailItem(RetailItem object2)
 {
  description = object2.description;
  price = object2.price;
  unitsOnHand = object2.unitsOnHand;
  cost = new CostData(object2.cost.wholeSale,object2.cost.Retail);
 }



public RetailItem( String descriptionGet,double pri, double 
unitsOnHandGet,double wholeSale,double retail)
{  
  description = descriptionGet;
  price = pri;
  unitsOnHand = unitsOnHandGet;
  cost = new CostData(wholeSale,retail);
}


public String toString()
{
  String str;

  DecimalFormat dollar = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00");

  str = "Description: " + description +
        "Item Price: " + price +
        "\nItem Number: " + unitsOnHand +
        "\nWhole Cost: $" + dollar.format(cost.wholeSale) +
        "\nRetail Price: $" + dollar.format(cost.Retail);

        return str;
}

public class CostData
{
 public double wholeSale;
 public double Retail;

 public CostData(double whole,double re)
 {
  wholeSale = whole;
  Retail = re;

 }

 public void setRetail(double re)
 {
  Retail = re;
 }

public void setWholeSale(double whole)
{
  wholeSale = whole;
}

public double getRetail()
{
  return Retail;
}
public double getWholeSale()
{
  return wholeSale;
}


}    
}
```

Here is the Cash Register class:

```
public class CashRegister
{
 private RetailItem retail;
 private int quantityItem;
 private final double SALES_TAX = 0.06;
 private int subTotal;


 public CashRegister()
{
  quantityItem = 0;
  subTotal = 0;
}


 public CashRegister(RetailItem retailObject,int quantity)
{
  retail = new RetailItem(retailObject);
  quantityItem = quantity;
}

public RetailItem getRetailItem()
{
  return new RetailItem(retail);
}

public double getSubTotal()
{
 return quantityItem * retail.cost.getRetail();//Here is where the problem is 

}

public double getTax()
{
  return SALES_TAX;
}
public double getTotal()
{
  return subTotal + SALES_TAX;
}

}
```

Comment: Write a getter, just like you already have for price and description.

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of options:

1. If they are in the same package, you can set the access of cost to
   default (remove the word `private` from in front of it.)
2. Change cost from `private` to `public`.
3. Create a default access (neither `private` nor `public`) `getCost()` method to return cost.
4. Create a public `getCost()` method to return cost.

The first option gives read/write access to any class in the same package as RetailItem.

The second option gives read/write access to all classes.

The fourth option gives read-only access to all classes.

`protected` access could also be an option.  Its like package access, but also gives read/write access to subclasses.

See also: [In Java, difference between default, public, protected, and private](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215497/in-java-difference-between-default-public-protected-and-private/12401576#12401576)